# mysql trim string or substring string? How to?

Tags: mysql

in a column I got this String:

> alt";s:24:"aaaaaaaa ";s:5:"title";s:126:"xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx.
> (xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx )
> "

I wanna trim this String in "alt" and "title" substrings. Already got two seperated columns for alt and for title.

alt= aaaaaaaa 
title: xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx.
(xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx )

What is the correct mysql way? Trim? or Substring?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think trim function would work here and asking whether to use trim or substring makes me wonder if you already know how to get the alt and the title.
Maybe thats the question you should be asking?

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty sure what you really need to know is how to get the alt and the title. If so, you need to provide more information about the string. i.e. the length the information included in the string. Is alt and title fixed in length? etc..

Comment: No its not fixed.
I have several length. The "s:126" is the char of following string.
And i have to set it on 6000 rows. It's not equal.

Comment: You need to tell us the story behind the string to be able for us to help you like what does s:24 and s:126 stands for etc.. You really need to give us more information about the string.

Comment: alt = my alt tag for my image
s:24 = char 24
"aaaaaa" = my string I would have
s:5: = says it has a title tag
"title" = my title tag from image
s:126 = char 126 from image tag title
"xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx. (xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx )" = my string I would have

The string is direct from an old database. Now i have two seperated columns for alt and title. So I need to seperate them clearly. And I have 6000 images to get through.

Comment: You wont get much help if you cannot really tell the story behind your string. You did not explain if s:24,s:5 and s:126 will always be present in your string. Is the title optional and may not be present in your string? Will the format of your string will always be like that? Although I would say your string format is a bit off there are cleaner way to format your string which you can easily separate them, but it might be too late to correct them anyway, so just try to explain your string in greater detail so anyone would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
select @alt:=substring(yourcolumn, 12, if(locate(';',yourcolumn,12)=0,length(yourcolumn),locate(';',yourcolumn,12))-13) as alt,
case locate('s:5:',yourcolumn, 12+length(@alt)) when 0 then '' else substring(yourcolumn, 33+length(@alt)) end as title 
from yourtable, (select @alt:='') x;
```

You can improve this based on your requirements, but this could be a start.

The sample query above assumed that s:24,s:5,s:126 are fixed when they are present and the format will always be the same except for the value of alt and title.